# How do I reduce a block diagram with just a line as a feedback loop, I dont get how it adds K to the denominator

Tags: continuous-signals, transfer-function, control-systems, feedback

[image]

How do I reduce a block diagram with just a line as a feedback loop, I dont get how it adds K to the denominator.
The bottom equation is supposed to be the answer.

Comment: Write $W(s) = R(s)-C(s)$, then $C(s)/W(s)$ equals the transfer function in the block.  Now do the algebra to find $C(s)/R(s)$ eliminating the intermediate $W(s)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the transfer function of the filter $H(s)$:

$$H(s)=\frac{K}{s(Js+B+KK_h)}=\frac{K}{D(s)}\tag{1}$$

From the diagram we have

$$C(s)=\big[R(s)-C(s)\big]H(s)\tag{2}$$

from which you get

$$\frac{C(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{H(s)}{1+H(s)}=\frac{K}{D(s)+K}\tag{3}$$

I'm sure you can fill in the details yourself.